# set buffer size of rpc call

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, gwt-rpc

we just ran into an issue where on the server side everything gets calculated and an object created with lists with lots of String contents, but the data is not transferred to the client.

After some research I found that with plain GWT there is RPCServletUtils (https://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/source/browse/trunk/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RPCServletUtils.java?r=8466) where it defines a buffer size, does anyone know how to overwrite this buffer size?

could there be any other parameter to tune? or any other experience with returning lots of data to the client via RPC?

the versions used are GWT 2.5.0 and SmartGWT 3.1

Comment: That buffer size is apparently only used for _reading_ data coming from the client, and it's only a buffer; ultimately everything is in memory.

Comment: oh, ok. makes sense. any other idea? the error displayed just states that I should check the server log, but there's nothing in the server log

Comment: You should see a "Exception while dispatching incoming RPC call" message with the stacktrace of the exception (see https://gwt.googlesource.com/gwt/+/2.5.0/user/src/com/google/gwt/user/server/rpc/RPCServletUtils.java, and yes, BTW, the code has moved to Git)

Comment: the problem was with the Xmx and Xms when starting tomcat. sorry! thanks for your responses anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the Xmx and Xms when starting tomcat.